# Observing Value for TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview, observers

I'm in the process of creating a tableview which changes dynamically in height when the number of cells increases or decreases. In order to complete this, I added an observer to my tableview:

```
tableView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize", options: .new, context: nil)
```

I receive this with the following method:

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    tableView.frame = CGRect(x: tableView.frame.origin.x, y: tableView.frame.origin.y, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: tableView.contentSize.height)
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

However, when I run this I get an error:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffeed414ff8)
```

I am sure these lines are causing the error and have already tried to call `super.observeValue(...)`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you doing this? The tableviews height is the height of the container on the screen, its contentSize.height is the height of its content that is being scrolled. When these two values are equal your table won’t scroll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way that Key Value Observing works in Objective C is that EVERY observed change for EVERY object you are observing goes through the same `observeValue` function.  Its entirely possible that your observe function is getting called before the tableView is ever loaded from the storyboard and thats why you are crashing.

You are supposed to check at least 2 things before you touch the tableView:

1. is the object parameter === to your tableView (ie is this the object you are looking for)
2. is the keyPath == to the keyPath that you want to observe on this object?